# Why photons do not have mass?

Tags: photons, mass, relativity

According to Einstein $E= mc^2$ so $m = E/ c^2$. So energy present in an atom contributes to its mass. So if a photon is a carrier of energy shouldn't it have mass since energy contributes to mass of an atom?

Answer (score 1):

$E=mc^2$ is the formula for an object with 0 momentum. If an object has momentum then the formula is $E^2/c^2=m^2 c^2+p^2$. A photon always has momentum and that momentum is $p=E/c$ so $m=0$

Comment: To me it always seems a stretch to incorporate or relate P to the other equation. P already has c in it. So when you add it to the other equation your adding c + c. It's redundant

Comment: Are you unaware of the four-momentum?

Comment: yes but that doesn’t explain why c was in the equation twice. It is redundant. Look at the equation and consider each time speed is involved.

Comment: It isn’t redundant. It is necessary both times for the units to work out.

Comment: I know, it like ad hoc.

Comment: But it isn’t ad hoc. It comes directly from the norm of the four-momentum. That is why I asked if you were familiar with it above. Your comments here make me think you are not aware of it.

Comment: I understand the four vectors and the reason for the calculation. Inserting c twice is still redundant and is a stretch based on the assumption that all the energy of a photon comes from linear motion. Its possible that most of the energy comes from something else related to frequency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84622/discussion-between-dale-and-bill-alsept).